# summary table for dataset in global environment

Tags: r

Is it a way I can get the data info from global environment into a summary table?

For example, I have a lot of data set named TXXX in my global environment, like
[image]

I would like to table that looks like this

[image]

Is it possible to also get all the variable list for each data using programing?
it will looks like this:

[image: (ls(pattern = "^T\d{4}$|^T\d{3}$"))]

Any way I can do that by programming? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get all the objects that starts with 'T' followed by 3 digit number in to a `list` , then loo over the `list` get the number of rows, 'Obs' and number of columns 'Variable'), `rbind` the `list` elements after creating the column 'Data' as the `names` of the `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^T\\d{3}$")),
        function(x) data.frame(Obs = nrow(x),
      Variable = ncol(x)))
out <- do.call(rbind,  Map(cbind, Data = names(lst1), lst1))
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

---

If we need the column names, we could use `rowr` to `cbind` the column names when the lengths are not the same

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^T\\d{3}$")), names)
library(versions)
available.versions('rowr') # // check for available version.  Not in CRAN
install.versions('rowr', '1.1.2') # // install a version
library(rowr) # // load the package
do.call(cbind.fill, c(lst1, fill = NA))
```

---

Or without installing `rowr`

```
mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
do.call(cbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mget(ls(pattern = '^T\\d{3}$')) %>%
   map_dfr(~ tibble(Obs = nrow(.x), Variable = ncol(.x)), .id = 'Data')
```

Comment: Wow. You are amazing. Knows everything!! Many thanks.

Comment: I just updated the post , adding one more step: Is it possible to get the variable lists out? Thanks. And also I have accepted the answer for the previous question. :)

Comment: II got error message `Warning in install.packages :   package ‘rowr’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)`. Any other way I can work around? Which version of R should I use?

Comment: @Stataq Iin my update, I showed a way to install the 'rowr'.  Pleaes install `versions` pacakge before installing the rowr

Comment: `package ‘versions’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)`. Do i need to upgrade or downgrade  r ? it seems like i could not install `versions` as well.

Comment: @Stataq I am using `R 4.0.2` your version of R is a bit old

Comment: i can choose higher version (4.0) . if I change it to that, will I lost all my old package? I switched to 3.63 back in May as 4.0 did not allow me to install some of the packages at that time.

Comment: @Stataq if it is to install just a package.  Then, we don't need to go that way.  I can updated another option

Comment: @Stataq please check whether the update works for you

Comment: `Error in `length<-`(mx) :   1 argument passed to 'length<-' which requires 2`

Comment: @Stataq sorry, a typo. fixed it. now it should work

Comment: @Stataq do you have data.frame or matrix.  if it is a matrix, then you need `lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^T\\d{3}$")), colnames)`

Comment: could you explain a bit more on `mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
do.call(cbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx))`?  `lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx)` equal to i=1,`length<-lst1[1] ...`? if I want the lst1 to be stored in a-z order, how should i modify this to achieve goal?

Comment: I think i know how it is pass through now. it is `length (lst1) <-mx`. Now my question is how can we make sure that each list in lst1 is sorted by a-z?

Comment: @Stataq the `length<-` is to append NA at the end when the list elements have less number of elements compared to the max length.  If you want to sort it.  You can use `sort` before the `length<-` assignment

Comment: Thanks. how can I sort a list?  I want to sort the varlist for each dataset, which was captured as a component  of the lst1? should I modify sth at `lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "*.CSV")), names)`? if so, how?

Comment: @Stataq can you post as a new question to understand it

Comment: Got it. Just post the new question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64994458/how-to-sort-each-object-in-a-list-that-contain-the-variable-list-from-multiple-d

Comment: Wow. You are fast! Many thanks. Up and will accept it once system allow me. :) I have one more question if you are open to i:, the additional step for the post 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968811/how-to-identify-the-columns-that-are-same-but-in-different-order-or-one-within-a