# how to identify the columns that are same but in different order or one within another one?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that capture a list of data's variables. It looks like this:
[image]

It can be build using codes:

```
df<-structure(list(cxr.CSV = c("project", "Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", 
"RecordPosition", "CXRDT", "CXRFIND", "CXRFNDSP", "CXRYN", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), cy1.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "CYSHPYN", 
"CYSHPDT", "CY1TMPT", "CYND", "CYNDSP", "CYDT", "CYTM", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), cy2.CSV = c("project", "Subject", 
"Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "CYSHPYN", "CYSHPDT", 
"CY2TMPT", "CYND", "CYNDSP", "CYDT", "CYTM", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), cy24.CSV = c("project", "Subject", "Site", 
"InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "CYSHPYN", "CYSHPDT", "CY1TMPT", 
"CYND", "CYNDSP", "CYDT", "CYTM", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), cy3.CSV = c("project", "Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", 
"RecordPosition", "CYSHPYN", "CYSHPDT", "CY3TMPT", "CYND", "CYNDSP", 
"CYDT", "CYTM", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), cy6.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "CYSHPYN", 
"CYSHPDT", "CY1TMPT", "CYND", "CYNDSP", "CYDT", "CYTM", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dlt.CSV = c("project", "Subject", 
"Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "DLTYN", "DLTAE", "DLTSP", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dm.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "BRTHYR", 
"DMAGE", "SEX", "SEXSP", "FEMCBP", "FEMCBPSP", "RACE", "RACESP", 
"ETHNIC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dov.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "DOVDT", 
"DOVAE", "DOVCM", "DOVCP", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), dov_1.CSV = c("project", "Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", 
"RecordPosition", "DOVDT", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ds.CSV = c("project", "Subject", "Site", 
"InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "DSDT", "DSREAS", "DSORTH", 
"DSWCSP", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    ds_1.CSV = c("project", "Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", 
    "RecordPosition", "DSDT", "DSREAS", "DSWCSP", "DSORTH", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dth.CSV = c("project", 
    "Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "DTHFCDT", 
    "DTHDT", "DTHDUR", "DTHREAS", "DTHROTH", "DTHCOMM", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dv.CSV = c("project", 
    "Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "DVYN", 
    "DVVIS", "DVIDDAT", "DVSTDAT", "DVENDAT", "DVCAT", "DVCATSP", 
    "DVCATCD", "DVTERM", "REWFLAG", "REWCOMP", "DVACN", "DVMETRPT", 
    "DVCLSDAT", "DVCLS", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), tegu.CSV = c("project", 
    "Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "EGYN", 
    "EGDT", "EGNOU", "EGTM", "EGORRES", "EGHR", "EGPR", "EGQRS", 
    "EGQTINT", "ECGRR", "EGQTCFC", "EGQTCBC", "EGQTCNS", "EGQTCO", 
    "EGQTCOSP", "EGRSAB01", "EGRSAB02", "EGRSAB03", "EGRSAB04", 
    "EGRSAB05", "EGRSAB06", "EGRSAB07", "EGRSAB08", "EGRSAB09", 
    "EGRSAB10", "EGRSAB11", "EGRSAB12", "EGRSAB13", "EGABNCOM", 
    "EGABNCS", "EGTMPT", "EGND"), tegu_1.CSV = c("project", "Subject", 
    "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "EGYN", "EGNOU", 
    "EGND", "EGTMPT", "EGDT", "EGTM", "EGORRES", "EGHR", "EGPR", 
    "EGQRS", "EGQTINT", "ECGRR", "EGQTCFC", "EGQTCBC", "EGQTCNS", 
    "EGQTCO", "EGQTCOSP", "EGRSAB01", "EGRSAB02", "EGRSAB03", 
    "EGRSAB04", "EGRSAB05", "EGRSAB06", "EGRSAB07", "EGRSAB08", 
    "EGRSAB09", "EGRSAB10", "EGRSAB11", "EGRSAB12", "EGRSAB13", 
    "EGABNCOM", "EGABNCS")), row.names = c(NA, -37L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to compare each column. If two data set the variables are same or one is completed included in another one. then mark them with same number. In the end, I would like to get a summary tables that looks like this:

[image]

No need to be exactly same so long as it catch the info. the tricky part are: tegu.CSV and tegu_1.CSV, ds.CSV and ds_1.CSV have same variable list in different order, dov.CSV has every variable that dov_1.CSV have and more. They need  to be in the same group.

How can I achieve this goal?

Additional step: what if I only want the dataset have same variable in a group? in that case, dov and dov1 will be in separated group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution, although not nice it might help you:

```
library(purrr)

my_data <- df %>%
  map(~.x[!is.na(.x)])
mySetDiff <- function(a, b) map2(a, b, setdiff)
my_data <- my_data %>% 
  outer(., ., mySetDiff) %>%
  apply(1, function(x) colnames(df)[which(map_dbl(x, length) == 0)]) %>%
  .[order(map_dbl(., length), decreasing = TRUE)]
  

i <- 1
my_list <- list()
repeat{
  
  if(length(my_data) == 0) break
  
  my_list[[i]] <- my_data[my_data[[1]]] %>% 
    unlist() %>%
    unique()
  
  my_data <- my_data[-which(names(my_data) %in% my_data[[1]])]
  
  i <- i + 1
}

my_list %>%
  imap(~tibble(Data = .x, Group = .y)) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

just note that `cy2.csv` and `cy3.csv` have `CY2TMPT`/`CY3TMPT` so they should not be in same group as `cy1.csv, cy6.csv, cy24.csv`

Comment: may I ask why we need to use `map2(a, b, setdiff)`, not `setdiff(a, b)`. What is the advantage of `map2`? `map2()` is new to me.

Comment: `FUN` argument in `outer` must be vectorised function. For more details read `?outer`. `map2` is coming from `purrr` package  for functionl programming.

Comment: what if we only want to keep the dataset that has same varlist in the same group? in that case, dov and dov_1 will not in the same group? how can we do that?

Comment: Not clear, you can have sets A = B, A < C, C = D. What should it keep in this case A and B or C and D?

Comment: what about keep a,b as a group and c d as a group?