# how to sort each object in a list that contain the variable list from multiple data

Tags: r, sorting

I have a list

```
lst1<-list(cxr.CSV = c("project", "Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", 
"RecordPosition", "CXRDT", "CXRFIND", "CXRFNDSP", "CXRYN"), cy1.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "CYSHPYN", 
"CYSHPDT", "CY1TMPT", "CYND", "CYNDSP", "CYDT", "CYTM"), cy2.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "CYSHPYN", 
"CYSHPDT", "CY2TMPT", "CYND", "CYNDSP", "CYDT", "CYTM"), cy24.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "CYSHPYN", 
"CYSHPDT", "CY1TMPT", "CYND", "CYNDSP", "CYDT", "CYTM"), cy3.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "CYSHPYN", 
"CYSHPDT", "CY3TMPT", "CYND", "CYNDSP", "CYDT", "CYTM"), cy6.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "CYSHPYN", 
"CYSHPDT", "CY1TMPT", "CYND", "CYNDSP", "CYDT", "CYTM"), dlt.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "DLTYN", 
"DLTAE", "DLTSP"), dm.CSV = c("project", "Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", 
"RecordPosition", "BRTHYR", "DMAGE", "SEX", "SEXSP", "FEMCBP", 
"FEMCBPSP", "RACE", "RACESP", "ETHNIC"), dov.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "DOVDT", 
"DOVAE", "DOVCM", "DOVCP"), dov_1.CSV = c("project", "Subject", 
"Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "DOVDT"), ds.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "DSDT", 
"DSREAS", "DSORTH", "DSWCSP"), ds_1.CSV = c("project", "Subject", 
"Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "DSDT", "DSREAS", "DSWCSP", 
"DSORTH"), dth.CSV = c("project", "Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", 
"RecordPosition", "DTHFCDT", "DTHDT", "DTHDUR", "DTHREAS", "DTHROTH", 
"DTHCOMM"), dv.CSV = c("project", "Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", 
"RecordPosition", "DVYN", "DVVIS", "DVIDDAT", "DVSTDAT", "DVENDAT", 
"DVCAT", "DVCATSP", "DVCATCD", "DVTERM", "REWFLAG", "REWCOMP", 
"DVACN", "DVMETRPT", "DVCLSDAT", "DVCLS"), tegu.CSV = c("project", 
"Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", "RecordPosition", "EGYN", 
"EGDT", "EGNOU", "EGTM", "EGORRES", "EGHR", "EGPR", "EGQRS", 
"EGQTINT", "ECGRR", "EGQTCFC", "EGQTCBC", "EGQTCNS", "EGQTCO", 
"EGQTCOSP", "EGRSAB01", "EGRSAB02", "EGRSAB03", "EGRSAB04", "EGRSAB05", 
"EGRSAB06", "EGRSAB07", "EGRSAB08", "EGRSAB09", "EGRSAB10", "EGRSAB11", 
"EGRSAB12", "EGRSAB13", "EGABNCOM", "EGABNCS", "EGTMPT", "EGND"
), tegu_1.CSV = c("project", "Subject", "Site", "InstanceName", 
"RecordPosition", "EGYN", "EGNOU", "EGND", "EGTMPT", "EGDT", 
"EGTM", "EGORRES", "EGHR", "EGPR", "EGQRS", "EGQTINT", "ECGRR", 
"EGQTCFC", "EGQTCBC", "EGQTCNS", "EGQTCO", "EGQTCOSP", "EGRSAB01", 
"EGRSAB02", "EGRSAB03", "EGRSAB04", "EGRSAB05", "EGRSAB06", "EGRSAB07", 
"EGRSAB08", "EGRSAB09", "EGRSAB10", "EGRSAB11", "EGRSAB12", "EGRSAB13", 
"EGABNCOM", "EGABNCS"))
```

Is it possible to sort each col by A-Z. There is no relationship col by col. This is list is using cbind created.  The code to build this list is

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "*.CSV")), names)
mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
do.call(cbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx))
```

Could we directly sort the .CSV in the list, or we need to make changes while we build the list? And how?

Currently the list looks like

[image]

The final list will looks like this:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop over the `list`, `sort` the elements first, then assign the `length` to that of 'mx', and return the sorted NA appended 'x1'

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) {
          x1 <- sort(x)
          length(x1) <- mx
           x1})
```

---

If we want to order the columns of the data based on the names, then

```
lst2 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "*.CSV")), function(x) {
           x[sort(names(x))]
         })
```

Comment: Sorry, I find out this only sort the col order. Please pardon me for not explaining the question better. I would like to sort the varlist for each .cvs col. it doesn't matter where a .cvs col is. I would like to know whether I could sort the variable list under each col name.

Comment: @Stataq I didn't understand.  Can you update with expected output

Comment: Just updated the post with before and expected after.

Comment: Do you think we could sort it while we read in `lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "*.CSV")), names)`

Comment: @Stataq oops, that is the issue.  I thought you would have done that i.e. you have to assign the output back `lst1 <- lapply(lst1, ..`

Comment: @Stataq that question is not clear.  We are updating the same list with the sorted values of the `list`

Comment: @Stataq When you say `read in sorted names`, I am not following.  You have a `list` of vectors.  which is sorted and made the lengths same.  Now, you can convert to a data.frame with `data.frame(lst1)`

Comment: Yes, The contain of list is the same. I just want each varlissts the read in from .CSV are sorted. I think I need to get them sort when we get `name`. But I don't know how. this happen before we fill in NA to build a same length one.

Comment: @Stataq I am not following you.  Do you want to read the file with `read.csv`

Comment: nope. `lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "*.CSV")), names)` read in the variables in each .csvfile with the order in it original .csv file. If I want to have them in A-Z order, what should I do? can I do `unlists(mget(ls(pattern="*.CSV")),sort))`, and then`lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "*.CSV")), names)`? Not sure whether it is doable.

Comment: @Stataq I guess you want to order the columns of the data  based on the names?

Comment: @Stataq in that case the updated code should work.  I didn't add more NA columns to it.  But it is ordered by column name